# Search substring in a list and give all the matching results comma separated

Tags: excel, list, search, excel-formula, substring

I have a list of items

```
My uncle eats a banana
My uncle eats a pear
My father eats an apple
My father eats a pear
```

If i enter the substring "uncle" i want to see "My uncle eats a banana,My uncle eats a pear"
If enter "pear" I want to see "My uncle eats a pear,My father eats a pear"

The tricky thing is that it cannot be a macro

Any ideas how I can get that to work?

I found on
https://www.xelplus.com/return-multiple-match-values-in-excel/

This formula:
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A5:A14=G4,B5:B14,""))

which works only for exact matches, not substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A$1:A$4,ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&B1&" "," "&A$1:A$4&" "))))
```

Or:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&B1&" "," "&A$1:A$4&" ")),A$1:A$4,""))
```

The 2nd option is to be CSE-entered in Excel-2019.

Comment: Cool thank you, I didn't know that was possible with filter   I was trying a combination of =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G4;I25:I30)) and textjoin

Thank you for your quick and very accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

As I'm using Excel 2016 (without TEXTJOIN function), My method while trying not to use VBA was like this excel file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7c09ykr4redog4k/Concat%20without%20VBA.xlsx?dl=1

Hope helps you